# Revoke privilege "create table" from public schema but not from custom made schema

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am trying to create an account that is only able to use "SELECT" within the mydb_schema.

I am able to revoke the creation of a tables in public schema in my database (mydb) from a specific role but I am not able to revoke the creation of tables within the schema (mydb_schema)  the role (user_role) is assigned to.

Can someone assist?  What am I missing?

Below are the commands I used as user postgres and as the owner of the schema. At the end I also altered the postgres account by using the noinherit just as a desperate test. No result.

```
\c mydb
 mydb=# create role user_account
 mydb=# alter role user_account login noinherit;
 mydb=# alter role user_account set search_path = 'mydb_schema';
 ##Up until this point I don't have SELECT pivileges but I can create a table within mydb_schema only and not in public.
 mydb=# grant select on all tables in schema mydb_schema to user_account;
 mydb=# revoke CREATE on SCHEMA public from public;
```

These are my databases:

```
List of databases
Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 6820 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
mydb      | seeker   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/seeker           +| 3465 MB | pg_default |
                                                              seeker=CTc/seeker
```

These are my schemas:

```
                          List of schemas
  Name      |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description
----------------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public         | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres | standard public schema
 mydb_schema    | seeker   | seeker=UC/seeker    +|
                |          | =UC/seeker           |
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution  [here in dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52691/how-can-i-create-readonly-user-for-backups-in-postgresql/102652#102652?newreg=a3f5f87753664a5398bc4303542a673a)

alter role servers_admin set default_transaction_read_only = 'ON';